# htaccess redirect subdomain to $_GET

Tags: .htaccess

Need some help with htaccess

For a sort of image storage site i need this:"

if users come to http:// subdomain.mysite.com/#RANDOMSTRING/ the server has to act like if it is the url: http:// subdomain.mysite.com/index.php?image=#RANDOMSTRING, but the visitor doesnt have to see this.

Also, on www. mysite.com (so not in the subdomain) there is a wordpress with htaccess for seo friendly urls. (Don't know if this has something to do with it, but because i need to upload files for http:// subdomain.mysite.com to ftp:// www.mysite.com/subdomain)

Hope to hear from you, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in the subdomain.mysite.com document root add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?image=$1 [L]
```

You may not need the `RewriteCond` at all because it seems your 2 domains (subdomain and www) are in different document roots.